# LEFT OUTER JOIN and NOT EXISTS query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, left-join

I am having hard time with a complex join, where I need to join the twice the same two tables, and be sure that the join is done every time only with a specific record (the most recent).

```
SELECT c.collection_id      AS collections, 
       s.strat_id           AS StrategyId, 
       s.strat_version      AS StrategyVersion, 
       ssb.side_ordering    AS SSB_SO, 
       ssb2.side_ordering   AS SSB2_SO, 
       Invoice1.invoice_id  AS Inv1ID, 
       Invoice2.invoice_id  AS Inv2ID, 
       Invoice1.printeddate AS Inv1PrintedDate, 
       Invoice2.printeddate AS Inv2PrintedDate 
  FROM dbo.collections AS c 
       INNER JOIN dbo.strategies AS s 
               ON c.collection_id = s.collection_id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.side_strat_brkrgs AS ssb 
               ON s.collection_id = ssb.collection_id 
                  AND s.strat_id = ssb.strat_id 
                  AND s.strat_version = ssb.strat_version 
       INNER JOIN dbo.strat_sides AS ss 
               ON ss.strat_side_id = ssb.strat_side_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.side_strat_brkrgs AS ssb2 
                    ON ssb2.collection_id = ssb.collection_id 
                       AND ssb2.strat_id = ssb.strat_id 
                       AND ssb2.strat_version = ssb.strat_version 
                       AND ssb2.side_ordering <> ssb.side_ordering 
       INNER JOIN dbo.strat_sides AS ss2 
               ON ss2.strat_side_id = ssb2.strat_side_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.newinvoiceitem AS InvoiceItem1 
                    ON ssb.collection_id = InvoiceItem1.collection_id 
                       AND ssb.side_ordering = InvoiceItem1.side_ordering 
                       AND s.strat_id = InvoiceItem1.strat_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS Invoice1 
                    ON Invoice1.invoice_id = InvoiceItem1.invoice_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.newinvoiceitem AS InvoiceItem2 
                    ON ssb2.collection_id = InvoiceItem2.collection_id 
                       AND ssb2.side_ordering = InvoiceItem2.side_ordering 
                       AND s.strat_id = InvoiceItem2.strat_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS Invoice2 
                    ON Invoice2.invoice_id = InvoiceItem2.invoice_id 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem1 
                          INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice1 
                                  ON tempInvoice1.invoice_id = 
                                     tempInvoiceItem1.invoice_id 
                    WHERE tempInvoiceItem1.collection_id = ssb.collection_id 
                          AND ssb.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem1.side_ordering 
                          AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem1.strat_id 
                          AND s.strat_version = tempInvoiceItem1.strat_version 
                          AND tempInvoice1.printeddate > Invoice1.printeddate) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem2 
                              INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice2 
                                      ON tempInvoice2.invoice_id = 
                                         tempInvoiceItem2.invoice_id 
                        WHERE 
               tempInvoiceItem2.collection_id = ssb2.collection_id 
               AND ssb2.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem2.side_ordering 
               AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem2.strat_id 
               AND s.strat_version = tempInvoiceItem2.strat_version 
               AND tempInvoice2.printeddate > Invoice2.printeddate) 
       AND c.collection_id = 16447
```

I obtain the following result:

```
16447   1   3   1   0   3785    3183    2010-05-06 17:52:00 2010-05-06 17:52:00 
16447   1   3   1   0   3785    4033    2010-05-06 17:52:00 2010-05-10 16:32:00 
16447   1   3   1   0   4137    3183    2010-05-20 17:08:00 2010-05-06 17:52:00 
16447   1   3   1   0   4137    4033    2010-05-20 17:08:00 2010-05-10 16:32:00
```

While I am actually expecting only the last row. Where am I wrong?

As you see I can't be using MAX() to retrieve the highest record, because I need to look for another property through a JOIN, and  I am forced to use a NOT EXIST

Comment: If this is for a large data set, for optimization and scalability I would consider getting around the left joins and break this down into smaller more manageable chunks :)

Comment: Can you work on the indentation a little? It's unreadable right now.

Comment: Your query is a bit complicated to get my head round. Generally, when one is looking for the most recent record, one will use MAX() to choose the highest invoice number or the latest date.

Comment: Your first query can't be parsed...and use [this](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) to format your query...

Comment: How can I format it better?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Put in line breaks where logical instead of wherever your editor wrapped them - indent tables and joins under the FROM, indent columns under the SELECT, make the `ON` conditions of joins visually relatable to the join they belong with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this predicate

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem1 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice1 
                   ON tempInvoice1.invoice_id = tempInvoiceItem1.invoice_id 
               WHERE tempInvoiceItem1.collection_id = ssb.collection_id 
                 AND ssb.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem1.side_ordering 
                 AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem1.strat_id 
               HAVING MAX(tempInvoice1.printeddate) = Invoice1.printeddate
                 OR Invoice1.printeddate IS NULL
               )                          
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem2 
                     INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice2 
                       ON tempInvoice2.invoice_id = tempInvoiceItem2.invoice_id 
                   WHERE tempInvoiceItem2.collection_id = ssb2.collection_id 
                     AND ssb2.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem2.side_ordering 
                     AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem2.strat_id 
                   HAVING MAX(tempInvoice2.printeddate) = Invoice2.printeddate
                     OR Invoice2.printeddate IS NULL
                   ) 
       AND c.collection_id = 16447
```

OR

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem1 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice1 
                   ON tempInvoice1.invoice_id = tempInvoiceItem1.invoice_id 
               WHERE tempInvoiceItem1.collection_id = ssb.collection_id 
                 AND ssb.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem1.side_ordering 
                 AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem1.strat_id 
               HAVING MAX(tempInvoice1.printeddate) = Invoice1.printeddate                     
               )                          
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM dbo.newinvoiceitem tempInvoiceItem2 
                     INNER JOIN dbo.newinvoice AS tempInvoice2 
                       ON tempInvoice2.invoice_id = tempInvoiceItem2.invoice_id 
                   WHERE tempInvoiceItem2.collection_id = ssb2.collection_id 
                     AND ssb2.side_ordering = tempInvoiceItem2.side_ordering 
                     AND s.strat_id = tempInvoiceItem2.strat_id 
                   HAVING MAX(tempInvoice2.printeddate) = Invoice2.printeddate
                   ) 
       AND c.collection_id = 16447 OR Invoice1.printeddate IS NULL
         OR Invoice2.printeddate IS NULL
```

Comment: This returns an empty set for me:(

Comment: This last version edited 39 minutes ago works. Can you explain the rationale?

Comment: I think that condition in both EXISTS() operators s.strat_version = tempInvoiceItem1.strat_version excessive, because for row data comparison we need same data sets.

Comment: Coming back on the topic, this turns the left outer join into an inner join... I would like to have NULL as well

Comment: No problem;) Just add a condition Invoice1.printeddate IS NULL/Invoice2.printeddate IS NULL. Answer updated